# chrony port 323 automatically open with firewalld?

Tags: rhel, firewalld, chrony

Documentation states `chrony` uses port 323udp by default, versus port 123udp that old NTP used.  But where is port 323 defined, because I do not see it in the default `/etc/chrony.conf` as it comes in a clean install of either RHEL-7.9 or RHEL 8.9.  Also, in either `/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml` which is the default firewall from a clean install, or even in my custom firewall xml file, I do not open either port 123 or port 323 and chrony seems to work - my time is correct the service is successfully running and `chronyc tracking` reports

```
Reference ID    : 1234ABCD (correctserver.com)
Stratum         : 4
Ref time (UTC)  : Tue Jan 02 20:35:42 2024
System time     : 0.000383474 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000296875 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000736834 seconds
Frequency       : 11.411 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.003 ppm
Skew            : 0.094 ppm
Root delay      : 0.024757780 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.091295145 seconds
Update interval : 1036.6 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

A `netstat -lun` does shows

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*
```

Biggest question is why is this like this regarding the firewall, since I am pretty sure I did not explicitly open port 323.  Where should I look for how port 323udp gets opened with firewalld (in RHEL-7.9) ?    And where does `chrony` explicitly have `port number = 323` defined?

`/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml` has only this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
</zone>
```

Comment: When operating as a client, chrony doesn't require any open *inbound* ports, and a typical default firewall configuration allows unrestricted outbound connections. Chrony will work fine regardless of whether or not port 323 is allowed by the firewall.